# Launch a GUI app on Linux Core (without desktop)

Tags: linux, gui, xfreerdp

Is it possible to launch a GUI app (like XFreeRDP) on a Linux without having to load the whole desktop ?
The goal is to have thin clients with Linux launching XFreeRDP uppon boot

Comment: you can just run the root-window of X11 & export display to it of course. the old way....or you can run a very minimal windowmanager (not a desktop manager) to run your app.

Comment: I'm confused. XFreeRDP, by definition, forwards a **desktop** connection. If you mean whether you can run an X11 app on the headless machine and have that display on the remote client: absolutely. All it takes is X11 client libraries and the app on the remote end, and ssh with X-forwarding enabled.

Comment: @tink I want to start my Linux in Core mode and start XFreeRDP which will connect to Windows RDS